# Hibernate or Database : Which is better place for foreign key constraints?

Tags: java, sql, database, hibernate

I have to create some `Foreign key` constraints on my two entities, I have implemented those relationship using `one to many mapping` in hibernate layer, my question is

1. What is better place to put such constraints: Hibernate or Database Tables or both?

I would appreciate some details as am not sure about right way of implementing constraints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those foreign keys have to be enforced by the appropriate constriants in the database. There is no way around that.

Your application (and thus Hibernate) won't be the only one accessing the data and it won't be the last one.